# javamail dir issues with windows

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, maildir

I am using `javamaildir` to read e-mail messages from the physical folder on windows machine.
I am passing the url as `"maildir:D:\\home\\test\\maildir"`. the direcotry maildir has the email message. I am able to  connect to the store `"maildir:D:\home\test\maildir"`, but when i am trying to getFolder("inbox"), I'm getting the exception saying 'folder 'INBOX' not found' is that folder named with inbox is by default for javamaildir?.

I need two clarifications:

1. Am i approaching in the right way?
2. There is a dot problem in accessing the folder using javamaildir on windows , can we hanlde it programatically...

Your suggetions will be helpful

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with reading the UNIX style maildir folders on Windows.  These folders typically have a inbox folder named `.INBOX` which seems to cause issues on Windows.  From what I could tell the javamaildir library expects the inbox folder to have the '.' in the name.

I don't really have a good solution, however I had a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491709/issue-processing-maildir-format-with-java-on-windows).  Not sure if it would be much help.  Good Luck!